# Plotting in Matlab by splitting up matrices

Tags: matlab, plot

I have two vectors `xline` and `yline` with 63 values in each, which I have derived from previous calculations. Out of these 63 values, The first 21 values of `xline` represent x co-ordinates of a line and similarly for `yline` they are y co-ordinates. The next 21 values are for a second line and so on.

How do I go about splitting these 63 values into 3 separate lines and plot them on an xy graph in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`plot(reshape(xline,[21 3])', reshape(yline,[21 3])')` should do the trick . Possibly you don't need to transpose both - I can never remember how Matlab likes its multi-line plots.

This is because Matlab stores matrices row-first: so when you reshape the array, you create multiple rows (becomes columns) and the `plot` command figures out what you want from there.

Comment: Didn't have to transpose. Worked like a gem! Thanks for your help,Appreciate it!